# Could not load type 'CKFinder.Connector.Connector'

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, ckfinder

Hا,
I am trying to use CKFinder with ckeditor in asp.net 4 but I am getting this error:

> Could not load type 'CKFinder.Connector.Connector'.
>   Could not load type 'CKFinder.Settings.ConfigFile'.
>   Unknown server tag 'CKFinder:Config'.

the dll is in the website's bin directory. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same problem You need to copy CKFinder.dll to your Bin folder.

Comment: @CanÜrek when you download CKFinder .NET version. It should be inside Bin\Release folder.

Comment: I can't found it. can you please help me.

Comment: @DhrutikaRathod Did you download CKFinder project? Build the solution and it should be under bin\release folder